# Regex to replace at least 5 digits in an character string

Tags: r, regex

I have a column in a data frame with addresses that are a composite of unit/house number, street name, locality, postcode, and phone number.

the postcode is a four digit number.

Here is an example:

`"26A JULIA STREET ANYTOWN 8523 71245632"`

I want to strip the phone numbers but keep the postcodes and other numbers to return:

`"26A JULIA STREET ANYTOWN 8523"`

I have tried the following:

`str_replace(string=field_name$ADDRESS, pattern="\\d{5,}", replacement="")`

It does not remove the phone numbers. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Could also use gsub. `gsub("\\s+\\d{5,}", "", mystring)` - with regex to clear leading space.

Comment: You can also capture everything until you find the 4 post code numbers. Use `sub("(.*\\d{4})","\\1", field_name$ADDRESS)`. This will work even in cases where there are no phone numbers.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me with the `data.frame` provided by **hrbrmstr**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally like the extra detail of the `stringi` package (and `stringr` just wraps it anyway):

```
library(stringi)
library(magrittr)

field_name <- data.frame(ADDRESS="26A JULIA STREET ANYTOWN 8523 71245632", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

stri_replace_last_regex(field_name$ADDRESS, "[[:digit:]]{5,}", "") %>% 
  stri_trim()
## [1] "26A JULIA STREET ANYTOWN 8523"
```